# MySQL Front-end Software

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database, I need to have an Excel-like front-end so that the system administrator can import Excel/CSV files directly into the database.

I used to use Navicat, but there was some problem with doing this. Is there any freeware that has the same functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use also Navicat for MySQL and frankly I do not experience problems importing/exporting Excel/CSV data...
Anyway, you can try [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), [MySQL-Front](http://www.mysqlfront.de/) or [DevArt MySQL Studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/)...